# Чем заархивирован бинарный файл?

Tags: java, python, c

Столкнулся с проблемой. Есть бинарный файл pbf, но он подвергнут компрессии. Каким именно способом не ясно. В разных пакетах  pbf  разные. Существуют пакеты без компрессии, с компрессией gzip и с неизвестной мне компрессией. Хотелось бы понять какой алгоритм сжатия мог быть использован в 3-м варианте.

Конкретизирую, пример :
Бинарный файл pbf https://yadi.sk/d/_XD64LODaH0sIg

```
1f 8b 08 00 00 00 00 00 02 03 5d 95 59 6c 14 75
1c c7 f7 37 7b ce 7f 8f ce fe 3b ec 31 9d 9d ce
4e f7 6e 0b 73 1f 65 39 5a da e5 2a a5 2c 10 53
05 c2 a1 15 09 9a 88 72 05 43 d0 a0 0f c4 54 44
4c 10 11 08 21 84 54 82 09 41 25 84 07 43 88 31
f8 82 24 12 83 3c 80 26 68 7c f2 81 f8 a2 31 fe
19 db e9 d2 ec 26 bb f9 fe 7e 9f ef ef da cd 70
7f 33 88 7e 75 cb b6 2d bb de dc be 7b 17 16 70
c4 e7 03 a0 28 bf 3f 43 49 0c 3d 99 9e 8c d7 72
81 97 84 72 48 4b 84 c3 98 27 f1 80 17 4f d0 57
d3 37 e2 12 f8 bb 03 8b 58 2b 85 3b 48 34 e8 45
e3 f4 cd f4 d5 38 d7 0c 6c 4a 5c 04 09 a7 48 30
04 e1 a9 60 84 3e cd fd 1e 47 7e 1f 56 89 1e 01
7a 4a 2f d0 df 89 47 93 bb a2 43 c9 ce e5 fd 41
ba b7 da 1e b7 d2 5a f2 33 e8 5d dd 3b 3f f9 c8
bf 71 28 3c 8f c2 32 61 90 57 48 72 99 1d d3 4c
67 2e 9f f5 98 62 74 a8 ed 11 b5 04 f7 12 22 0a
b1 29 a2 93 be 2a de 61 9e 8f 76 d0 d1 77 61 6f
36 3e 96 ff 00 ca c5 a4 d2 99 0c 56 a3 8f a0 1b
67 48 7a dc 2b 80 e8 9b e2 b9 24 f6 b5 c5 fb dd
31 12 9e 51 84 be 23 5e 4e a2 70 ce dd 5c 9b 37
06 43 4f e4 6f e3 5a 87 52 34 c2 dd d0 45 b8 a7
8e 8c 37 3e 72 e3 38 c1 87 32 78 90 44 92 1e 69
d2 e7 f2 ff e2 2b c0 d8 85 cd a9 d7 42 38 c1 09
5c 81 8f 85 46 04 29 75 1e 06 51 88 e3 58 3e 12
e2 63 66 60 f1 dc ed 3d 8b e5 02 7b 13 ae 83 db
17 f6 5c 22 f4 a9 e2 b1 34 0a 47 5d bd 7d b6 1e
88 e0 02 d1 59 af 9f 94 ab 0f 04 42 10 48 c4 a4
88 e0 c3 a1 9e 82 cd b9 f4 9c 16 fa 97 d2 93 34
5a 96 71 f5 54 8b 7e bf fa 30 8b 16 33 78 29 d1
d3 9e ee d0 27 6b 7f 66 27 e1 27 6a 94 f1 c5 c2
5c 95 8d 86 7c 5b 45 3e 36 01 b5 af a0 8e 29 21
cc f8 de 87 e6 79 98 84 49 ea 9c 7f 70 44 62 f7
f1 3d ac 80 f0 0e 62 94 f1 8c 36 b8 46 d7 a9 5a
e2 0a d5 88 f9 12 61 be 3b 46 d0 3a 5e 21 08 a1
a3 d0 73 04 e6 b2 14 17 4e f8 de 83 91 83 87 a0
d1 9c a0 fe a1 86 9b 15 76 3c 53 63 04 96 e9 61
06 4a 7b 22 a5 e0 68 97 e4 27 67 a8 e8 f5 85 19
5c 51 d8 68 45 6c f6 b9 c3 64 5b 7e 99 df 98 8f
45 14 ef c0 b7 80 04 38 e8 20 01 9e 04 be 04 fa
49 f2 7c f4 8f 00 6b 26 c6 7d a3 88 8f e1 54 6a
e7 32 3e c6 06 96 51 77 41 29 04 7b 7c 99 c0 c1
c2 69 d0 1f 40 7d 9d 50 4f 0c a4 2e 42 6d bc a2
66 9a ea e2 1a 9f 52 2b 3c 5f 91 99 4c 61 14 37
c4 93 80 04 56 4a f1 35 e1 3a b5 67 bb 79 11 b6
8e d8 7a cf 61 78 0f 44 ae 96 69 64 2e 53 a3 b7
a1 2e 31 9b b9 65 19 99 55 39 31 75 18 46 4a 5c
49 94 4a c7 e1 5b 28 14 44 4e 16 ef c2 3b d0 90
74 d6 c6 76 6c 18 f1 3e 3d 74 8a 42 75 e6 1e 9c
82 6b f0 56 53 dd d1 67 8a f8 8b a7 63 e4 bc 31
ce 02 7d b6 ff 6c f1 5c e0 0c 8c ad d7 da db 3e
87 d7 8d ea 02 23 37 a7 37 bb ba fd 53 8a 7e 1b
a2 2f 67 17 cc 59 53 fe 0d 3e 84 72 ce 30 ca ca
d8 81 74 ae 5c 76 aa bb 97 6e 31 36 76 bd 92 fb
1e 96 fc 00 da 1b f9 5c d0 48 e6 93 bd f9 33 70
06 d6 2e 9a df f5 23 ec ef 8c 7f 44 6d ab b6 77
e5 3b 7a c3 69 ed 57 48 3b 39 25 57 b4 ac 03 2f
ac 99 37 56 35 92 9f 50 2b e7 b5 e5 82 3f c3 f2
af a9 b1 6a 78 65 e0 63 a8 39 a1 95 c9 d5 5d e5
74 3a 9d cc d1 5a 60 11 76 48 c3 82 77 fc 6e f7
20 47 80 c9 f0 62 22 51 e2 8e 83 8e 02 08 99 97
20 52 f3 37 ca 15 3f f2 c5 a8 50 45 b5 fb 38 d6
bd 65 67 cb 2d ef 39 8f 8b 28 12 c5 59 a2 8b 9e
1e a5 8f f5 5d 28 e2 b3 b0 ab 56 71 91 7c 0b 32
31 ff 70 09 a1 10 2e 13 5d f2 ba c8 d2 27 e6 1f
29 ad 28 f1 bc c0 c4 a4 82 24 98 8d 0b 30 1e 00
53 70 0d ba 5a 0c fe aa 3f 2c 23 99 77 ff f2 05
cf 00 d1 37 16 3e a8 e0 10 b5 a9 e9 12 c5 16 e2
d2 a2 6b 55 14 0d e3 4e a2 97 3c 3d 49 df 5a 78
bf 22 5d 86 13 90 60 06 37 6f 38 02 38 47 12 ca
9e 65 9b 0b 4a 03 75 9c ea 6b 8e 9f 00 2e 32 bc
7c 64 a8 bf b9 7c 90 8b 34 d6 0f 0f 8f f4 af 1a
e2 82 cd 75 eb c6 46 b9 e0 aa 75 8d 25 4b a4 36
14 57 14 59 d7 6d c3 d4 c9 db 91 30 62 9e 13 57
4d 3f 00 c4 81 9d 7b 5e 94 fc 08 56 49 61 14 5c
ab e8 b2 dc 8a c8 86 6a d9 53 82 aa 18 a6 aa 58
e4 cb 8c 60 99 86 62 1a b6 14 45 b4 67 e9 f1 96
a1 68 ba 6a db 12 83 12 b3 0a 3e 93 a2 6b e6 4c
4d 53 73 08 a2 48 71 14 6d 69 73 ba a2 2e 5b 9a
69 ea b2 d9 d2 93 41 3e 9c d6 ae 2d 4b b3 35 6d
3a c3 34 74 53 56 49 e2 94 60 c8 b6 43 2a ca b2
ee 21 a6 63 29 9a e2 d8 b3 04 db f2 3c 34 5b 36
1d 32 7e eb 2a 74 db 31 ed d6 0c cb b6 65 65 4a
d0 2c c5 32 1c 4d 51 b5 d9 82 fe 8c 87 62 3d 33
bc ec c8 8e e3 7a cc 2c ac b1 77 ff ff b7 51 5a
6e 63 91 97 6d 7a ee 53 63 6b 33 2d 2b 06 a9 26
db ca 34 a2 99 8e ac db 9a ac a9 cf 2c 46 31 55
6b 66 b9 64 6e 59 76 d4 59 88 6a ce ce d0 66 79
98 9e e0 18 ba a3 d8 86 a2 b4 6e 9b 9c 48 d1 2b
87 c4 7d f0 1f 55 db d3 3b 7e 08 00 00
```

Бинарный файл pbf с компрессией gzip: https://yadi.sk/d/cAaibv2cfzhGzA

```
1a fb 10 0a 09 6d 61 63 61 72 74 68 75 72 12 1e
12 08 00 00 01 01 02 02 03 03 18 02 22 10 09 aa
17 aa 0d 2a 1d 04 65 1e 27 06 33 0e 07 07 12 1c
12 08 00 04 01 01 02 02 03 03 18 02 22 0e 09 b4
17 bc 0d 22 01 03 2b 04 3f 14 37 16 12 1b 12 08
00 05 01 01 02 02 03 03 18 02 22 0d 09 c2 17 b4
0d 1a 52 04 5e 0e a8 01 22 12 16 12 08 00 06 01
07 02 02 03 03 18 02 22 08 09 9e 1a e8 0d 0a 03
00 12 32 12 08 00 08 01 09 02 02 03 03 18 02 22
24 09 c8 20 90 11 72 0b 45 11 1f 49 41 05 09 2d
29 13 0d 37 17 33 11 9d 01 2d 4f 2d 3b 11 e1 03
5d 45 07 2f 02 12 30 12 08 00 0a 01 01 02 02 03
03 18 02 22 22 09 c8 20 90 11 6a 0b 45 11 1f 49
41 05 09 1f 1d 21 19 37 17 33 11 9d 01 2d 4f 2d
25 0b 45 0f e1 02 43 12 2d 12 08 00 0b 01 0c 02
02 03 03 18 02 22 1f 09 b4 20 d0 10 5a 0b 1b 09
0b 85 01 77 19 0d 59 21 8f 01 27 25 11 31 1f 11
05 29 0b e1 01 2b 12 18 12 08 00 0d 01 01 02 02
03 03 18 02 22 0a 09 c2 20 a2 11 12 00 0f 0d 41
12 16 12 08 00 0e 01 0c 02 02 03 03 18 02 22 08
09 d0 20 ae 11 0a 07 1d 12 1e 12 08 00 0f 01 09
02 02 03 03 18 02 22 10 09 8e 21 ca 12 2a 1b 31
25 35 07 2b 01 23 0d 41 12 18 12 08 00 10 01 07
02 02 03 03 18 02 22 0a 09 8e 21 ca 12 12 0e 1c
06 18 12 44 12 08 00 11 01 09 02 02 03 03 18 02
22 36 09 a2 21 fe 12 b2 01 10 38 24 60 16 6e 06
12 0e 1a 1e 1a 24 1c 0c 06 4e 1e 22 16 a4 01 44
0a 06 1a 1a 14 1c 08 06 1c 0c 36 04 40 2e 68 2c
40 30 24 14 c2 01 ba 01 12 16 12 08 00 12 01 09
02 02 03 03 18 02 22 08 09 9c 25 92 17 0a 07 0b
12 16 12 08 00 13 01 09 02 02 03 03 18 02 22 08
09 9c 25 92 17 0a 04 08 12 24 12 08 00 14 01 07
02 02 03 03 18 02 22 16 09 9c 25 92 17 42 04 06
01 04 0e 0c 22 08 1e 00 12 06 2c 24 38 1a 12 16
12 08 00 15 01 09 02 02 03 03 18 02 22 08 09 e2
26 f4 17 0a 48 18 12 16 12 08 00 16 01 09 02 02
03 03 18 02 22 08 09 da 29 e0 19 0a 40 10 12 47
12 08 00 17 01 09 02 02 03 03 18 02 22 39 09 9a
2a f0 19 aa 01 d8 02 50 10 00 0c 07 1a 29 14 0b
06 00 62 20 1c 0c 8e 01 2a b6 01 3c 12 02 1e 07
10 00 8c 01 52 a4 01 aa 01 aa 02 a2 03 44 4e 22
14 78 1c 2c 14 1e 0a 12 6a 12 08 00 18 01 09 02
02 03 03 18 02 22 5c 09 9a 2a f0 19 ba 02 2a 0e
b2 02 46 0c 00 0e 07 1c 2b 0c 07 10 00 3c 12 4a
1e 1e 06 90 01 2c 8a 01 2e 14 02 1a 07 0e 00 86
01 4e 7e 80 01 46 52 8e 02 fc 02 4c 52 28 14 66
18 2a 10 1e 14 10 2c 10 42 26 76 08 26 05 50 23
22 03 08 00 10 28 34 3c 3e 18 12 28 31 14 0b 28
20 52 3a 12 16 12 08 00 19 01 07 02 02 03 03 18
02 22 08 09 c0 36 e6 20 0a 0d 1b 12 c4 01 12 08
00 1a 01 1b 02 02 03 1c 18 02 22 b5 01 09 f4 11
a4 0b ea 04 14 36 0e 66 00 50 0a 1c 0c 12 16 16
6c 48 1c 0c 14 04 48 02 d2 01 31 24 05 2c 00 18
04 7e 24 9e 01 34 dc 01 3c 54 1e 3c 0e 42 16 a8
01 2a 66 28 32 18 52 32 40 2a 1c 16 32 28 1c 1c
28 30 10 18 24 50 12 46 20 9a 01 0a 1e 14 22 16
1c 2a 1e ba 02 76 68 36 a8 01 62 4e 38 34 2c 84
01 86 01 20 1a 2a 18 46 18 ae 02 50 ca 01 3c 22
10 60 1a 48 18 30 14 32 1a 20 16 84 01 4e 26 1a
26 20 22 26 94 01 c6 01 24 24 20 1a 30 20 d2 01
82 01 46 22 34 14 38 12 38 0c 4c 0a 1c 00 34 06
9c 02 0a 3c 10 d6 01 9c 01 b8 01 7c 52 32 6a 3a
36 20 12 af 01 12 08 00 1d 01 1b 02 02 03 1c 18
02 22 a0 01 09 a0 41 a0 25 a2 04 9f 01 59 55 33
13 0f ab 01 71 35 29 3d 35 1d 15 2d 19 4f 13 9b
02 09 81 01 0b 67 19 3d 15 51 27 e7 01 91 01 27
1d 35 35 27 31 59 7b 17 1d 27 27 39 29 75 47 61
35 5d 23 69 1d cb 01 43 d1 01 33 73 21 1d 05 35
11 21 11 2d 21 9f 01 9f 01 53 3f 3b 23 d5 01 79
1f 0d 93 02 63 29 13 23 21 1b 2d 07 17 33 e3 01
17 39 1d 31 1d 25 37 37 7b 5b 51 2f 59 29 35 11
99 02 4b 2f 0f 1d 05 db 01 49 b7 02 59 29 07 4b
04 95 01 2a 39 06 4b 11 4f 23 27 17 17 17 11 1d
09 33 04 3f 12 39 12 08 00 1e 01 09 02 02 03 03
18 02 22 2b 09 c0 36 e6 20 8a 01 10 18 1c 20 0e
0e 26 1a 94 01 34 0a 04 0a 0a 36 ac 01 08 2a 03
46 27 28 03 0a 00 0c 02 06 28 32 38 3a 1a 14 12
16 12 08 00 1f 01 07 02 02 03 03 18 02 22 08 09
d6 39 e6 25 0a 08 0b 12 19 12 08 00 20 01 07 02
02 03 03 18 02 22 0b 09 92 3a a6 25 12 a0 01 72
2a 28 12 16 12 08 00 21 01 07 02 02 03 03 18 02
22 08 09 8e 3b 84 26 0a 0a 06 12 27 12 08 00 22
01 09 02 02 03 03 18 02 22 19 09 98 3b 8a 26 4a
26 1c 1c 1e 10 0c 22 24 22 1e 36 46 a6 01 66 04
01 36 1e 12 16 12 08 00 23 01 07 02 02 03 03 18
02 22 08 09 f6 3c e0 27 0a 30 1c 12 18 12 08 00
24 01 09 02 02 03 03 18 02 22 0a 09 bc 3e dc 28
12 06 02 5e 52 12 16 12 08 00 25 01 07 02 02 03
03 18 02 22 08 09 ac 3f b8 29 0a 0b 07 12 1f 12
08 00 26 01 07 02 02 03 03 18 02 22 11 09 c4 3e
da 28 22 ae 01 98 01 0e 10 44 60 5c 8a 01 12 1d
12 08 00 27 01 09 02 02 03 03 18 02 22 0f 09 ac
3f b8 29 22 42 3c 12 16 3a 52 66 98 01 1a 08 4c
49 4e 45 41 52 49 44 1a 08 46 55 4c 4c 4e 41 4d
45 1a 05 52 54 54 59 50 1a 05 4d 54 46 43 43 22
0f 0a 0d 31 31 30 34 34 38 35 36 34 35 36 34 39
22 12 0a 10 57 20 4d 61 63 61 72 74 68 75 72 20
42 6c 76 64 22 03 0a 01 4d 22 07 0a 05 53 31 34
30 30 22 0f 0a 0d 31 31 30 34 34 38 35 36 30 35
32 37 38 22 0f 0a 0d 31 31 30 32 31 35 36 32 31
37 31 30 32 22 0f 0a 0d 31 31 30 32 31 35 37 36
35 31 36 35 38 22 0b 0a 09 4d 61 63 61 72 74 68
75 72 22 0f 0a 0d 31 31 30 34 34 37 35 31 33 34
32 38 38 22 10 0a 0e 4d 61 63 61 72 74 68 75 72
20 42 6c 76 64 22 0f 0a 0d 31 31 30 34 34 37 35
31 33 34 34 33 36 22 0f 0a 0d 31 31 30 34 34 38
36 33 39 32 38 38 31 22 0d 0a 0b 57 20 4d 61 63
61 72 74 68 75 72 22 0f 0a 0d 31 31 30 32 34 30
37 33 36 36 34 30 36 22 0f 0a 0d 31 31 30 32 31
35 36 35 31 30 32 39 30 22 0f 0a 0d 31 31 30 34
34 38 35 37 37 33 38 33 33 22 0f 0a 0d 31 31 30
32 36 35 34 36 30 32 32 31 35 22 0f 0a 0d 31 31
30 35 30 38 39 34 33 36 30 30 34 22 0f 0a 0d 31
31 30 34 34 36 39 37 31 33 31 39 38 22 0f 0a 0d
31 31 30 34 34 36 39 37 31 33 31 38 37 22 0f 0a
0d 31 31 30 32 36 33 38 30 36 39 35 36 32 22 0f
0a 0d 31 31 30 32 31 35 36 32 34 38 39 36 38 22
0f 0a 0d 31 31 30 32 36 33 38 30 37 38 38 30 31
22 0f 0a 0d 31 31 30 33 37 31 37 35 39 33 31 32
33 22 0f 0a 0d 31 31 30 33 37 31 37 35 39 33 31
32 34 22 0f 0a 0d 31 31 30 32 31 35 36 32 34 31
37 33 36 22 0f 0a 0d 31 31 30 34 34 38 36 30 39
30 39 39 31 22 0f 0a 0d 4d 61 63 61 72 74 68 75
72 20 46 77 79 22 07 0a 05 53 31 31 30 30 22 0f
0a 0d 31 31 30 34 34 37 34 37 34 38 36 32 33 22
0f 0a 0d 31 31 30 34 34 38 35 37 37 33 33 38 37
22 0f 0a 0d 31 31 30 32 31 35 35 39 33 30 38 31
30 22 0f 0a 0d 31 31 30 33 36 39 30 34 38 33 30
33 32 22 0f 0a 0d 31 31 30 32 36 35 34 36 30 31
36 32 37 22 0f 0a 0d 31 31 30 32 34 30 36 39 37
30 30 39 32 22 0f 0a 0d 31 31 30 33 36 39 30 34
38 33 30 32 36 22 0f 0a 0d 31 31 30 32 34 30 36
39 37 30 30 39 33 22 0f 0a 0d 31 31 30 32 36 35
34 36 30 31 36 36 33 22 0f 0a 0d 31 31 30 32 39
35 34 39 31 38 35 31 31 22 0f 0a 0d 31 31 30 35
30 38 39 34 36 35 31 31 34 28 80 20 78 01
```

Бинарный файл pbf, подвергнутый компрессии неизвестным алгоритмом https://yadi.sk/d/ybexy5hOzGHpiQ

```
78 9c 93 7a c8 58 c1 c4 c5 52 90 58 92 a1 d1 a0
20 c5 5c 9a 99 22 c5 5e 94 98 99 53 9e 58 29 c5
9e 91 99 9e 01 62 70 96 14 25 26 67 97 54 16 a4
2a 71 70 b1 19 1a 18 5a 5a 5a 2a 71 71 71 24 17
e5 17 17 67 e6 a5 83 44 cd 0d cc 4c 2d cc 95 d8
20 86 81 44 d2 8b 12 53 52 0d 85 f8 25 18 85 58
18 18 18 19 95 58 39 e7 08 ef 52 44 11 d8 22 dc
a3 84 22 b0 47 78 99 92 90 94 04 93 10 1b 03 13
13 33 33 8b 12 1f 67 87 f0 03 05 29 93 63 8c 05
01 0e eb 18 51 14 f7 88 9c 43 d5 bd 46 e4 1b aa
c0 3d 91 27 ca 00 f1 7c 2c 6f
```

В примерах использованы разные файлы, т.е. 3-й файл не идентичен второму или первому. Это лишь пример.

Comment: Так вы проверили, что это не gzip? Еще вариант - .zip архив, с измененным расширением.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Да пробовал gzip. Не открыл. Может есть какие-то настройки степени сжатия?

Comment: Выкладывать бинарные файлы в виде обработанного текста — это гениально

Comment: @andreymal как их выкладывать?

Comment: @KonstantinEmelyanov ну хотя бы в виде HEX-представления, чтобы обработка текстовыми редакторами ничего не убила

Comment: А лучше продублировать ссылкой на файл для удобства

Comment: @andreymal хорошо, спасибо, понял.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93524/discussion-between-konstantin-emelyanov-and-andreymal).

Comment: Как заявляет утилита `file`, третий файл сжат с zlib. И таки да, он у меня успешно разжимается утилитой `zlib-flate -uncompress`

Answer (score 2):

99% что это [google protobuf](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/), это широко распространенный бинарный формат для обмена сообщениями между программами по утвержденному протоколу, возможность кодирования и декодирования реализована для большого количества языков программирования (c++, java, python, javascript и др)

Для обычной работы с ним он должен сопровождаться файлом протокола `.proto` с описанием полей, по нему для клиентов генерируется класс-десериализатор.

Без него, высокой долей вероятности его можно расшифровать при помощи [`protoc`](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/downloads?hl=RU), однако названия полей будут утеряны, информации о них нет в бинаре, вместо ключей будут индексы...

```
protoc --decode_raw < msg.bin
```

---

ps: конечно будет больше шансов если Вы предоставите сам бинарный файл

pps: если Вы откроете [google earth web](https://earth.google.com/web/), и взглянете на закладку network в отладчике Вы увидите море запросов pbf файлов с серверов гугла, в них они стримят геометрию и текстуры для рендеринга земли в риалтайм.

Comment: 99% - это сильное заявление! Поставлю плюс пока!

Comment: @0-LevelUNIXMonk ну надо взгчнуть на сам бинарь, для 100% уверенности, но расширение до боли знакомое

Comment: Да, это protocol binary format.  Я уже воспользовался protoc и у меня есть proto файл. Но в дополнение ко всему этот pbf, в моём случае, ещё и сжимается. Т.е.  после того как сообщение было переведено в формат pbf оно подвергается компрессии.  Поэтому перед тем как расшифровать сам pbf его нужно разархивировать. А вот чем его сжимали не понятно.

Comment: @KonstantinEmelyanov тогда однозначно добавляйте его в вопрос, если можете, конечно